# JPA2 Criteria Query JOIN

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have following class ( entity )

```
@Entity
public class  Magazine {
    private int id ;
    private String magazine;

            //getters and setters
}

// tracking the magazine arrival
@Entity 
public class MagazineIn {
    private int id;
    private java.util.Date inDate;
    private java.util.Date magdate;

    @OneToOne
    private Magazine mag ; 
            //getters and setters

}
```

Now i want to get all arrival status of all magazine , whether 
magazine has in or not

using criteria query

following is code

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);

        Root<MagazineIn> magIn = cq.from(MagazineIn.class);
    Join<Magazine,MagazineIn> mag =  magIn.join("mag" , JoinType.LEFT);

        cq.multiselect(mag.get("magazine") , magIn.get("magdate") , 
            magIn.get("inDate"));
    TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery(cq);
```

But i am not getting  all the magazine listing with indate and magdate null.RIGHT JOIN is not supported. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity relationships changes are not possible you could consider changing the root of your query to Magazine and use a subquery which correlates on the 'mag' variable.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that you would indeed need a right join to do this. You could just have the reverse `OneToOne` association from `Magazine` to `MagazineIn`, and query from the magazine to the magazineIn with a left join.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using collection in Magazine

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mag",FETCHTYPE.LAZY)
List<MagazineIn> arrivals
```